# JQuery's .append() executes 6 times instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a marquee type thing by scrolling vertically through the banners and then moving each to the bottom after it is out of view. I can't figure out why the banner is being appended six times. I realize that it's not quite complete so don't make a remark about that please. If you have a better suggestion, let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/vCuHc/2/

**EDIT:** How can I append the top element to the bottom and then remove the top element also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have six elements with the same class. This script runs once for each of the those elements.

Change the code that it runs *once* by appending to the parent div after the animations complete and not at the end of *every* animation.

Answer (score 1):

It's being called against every element in the result of `$('.tornado_banner')`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
function(){
...
        $("#banner_container").append(
            '<a class="tornado_banner" id="banner_alberta" href="#" style="top:' + elementNum * -130 + 'px">&nbsp;</a>'
        );
```

Try

```
function(){
   $(this).detach().appendTo("#banner_container");
}
```

Comment: That's pretty helpful except for some reason it executes first. http://jsfiddle.net/vCuHc/2/

Comment: this function should be the callback of the animate function. Currently you have it as standalone code.

Comment: Would that not execute for all six items rendering them the same?

Comment: Your right. Now that I think about it, have you considered putting all your divs within a second div and just run one animate function on the containing div? It will most likely look smother, no white lines between banners, and then you wont have to worry about multiple callbacks.

Comment: Hmm. Great pointer. I got it all fixed and working now, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your edit correctly,

```
var first = jQuery("#banner_container a:first");
jQuery("#banner_container").append(first);
```

That will remove the first element while appending it to the end of the list.